# Apache rewrite URL to local url with port. Doesn't rewrite but redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to achieve this:

http://mydomain/api/someApiCall?param=1&param=2

backed by actual url:

http://mydomain:8080/app/someApiCall?param=1&param=2

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

....

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://mydomain:8080/app/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It actually redirects requests to http://mydomain:8080/app/someApiCall?param=1&param=2

Is there a way to work it as usual rewrite (i.e. not sending back 302 but just providing the content). It is the same server physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load mod_proxy then you can use the `P` flag, which will proxy instead of redirect. But you can't do it directly since specifying a port will cause it to redirect otherwise regardless.